# EVGA X58 SLI motherboard doesn't boot with new memory

Tags: memory, motherboard, dram, multi-channel

`EVGA X58 SLI` (EVGA E758-A1 3-Way SLI (x16/x16/x8) LGA 1366 Intel X58 ATX Intel Motherboard) was normally working with three [CORSAIR DOMINATOR 6GB (3 x 2GB) 240-Pin DDR3 Triple Channel Kit Desktop Memory Model TR3X6G1600C8D](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820145224R) . I recently purchased 6 new [CORSAIR XMS3 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 Desktop Memory Model CMX8GX3M2A1333C9](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820145315)  and the motherboard stopped to booting.

It still boots with:

1) old 3 dimms plugged in 3 green slots

2) new 1 dimm plugged in 1 green slot (all DIMMs checked this way)

3) new 2 dimms plugged in 2 green slots

It doesn't boot if any black slot used.

[image]

The plugging was checked multiple times, MB was cleaned with air, contact looks ok.

What may affect the situation except MB damage?

When, halting MB displays numbers F3, 68,69 alternating. First 2 codes are not described in manual (http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/132-BL-E758.pdf) while 69 means "Initializing cache controller".

Now playing with BIOS settings, but have no guiding idea (except lowering frequency). May be it is possible to disable multichannel or something? BIOS pages are slightly different, than in manual.

**UPDATE**

Processor model is  Intel i7 920 2.66Ghz 8M LGA1366

Test with another identical motherboard gave the same results! So unprobably that motherboard is damaged! This is some incompatibility or misconfiguration.

Resetting CMOS to factory defaults didn't help.

Lowering memory frequency didn't help.

**UPDATE 2**

Unfortunately it is said in manual that MB supports "up to 12 gb" of memory. Can this be overcame?

**UPDATE 3**

How to find which firmware/BIOS version I use? Can BIOS upgrading help? It is written in BIOS chip "ix58 s22d". What does this mean? I found "new" BIOS version here http://www.evga.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=161535&mpage=1. Does it match? It is said "This BIOS is ONLY for the EVGA X58 LE Motherboard (part number 141-BL-E757-)". My MB is "EVGA E758-A1 3-Way SLI (x16/x16/x8) LGA 1366 Intel X58 ATX Intel Motherboard".

Comment: Nothing except a defective motherboard would explain this behavior.  The only thing I noticed is that the new memory is slower then your old memory.  What size is the memory and what processor are you using exactly?  Without this information I can't suggest other possible causes.

Comment: Processor is `i7`. Memory modules are 2 gb each old, and 4 gb each new.

Comment: Which processor model exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound, can't see since not near for now :) Btw how processor model can affect memory working?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if it wasn't important.

Comment: I believe it is important, just asking to describe how, please. If it is not top secret information of course. In latter case please don't say me! :)

Comment: What is your BIOS version? (It should be displayed on the screen when you boot.) If it's not [the latest](http://www.evga.com/support/download/showdlinfo.aspx?id=746&type=N&acctype=BIOS&accversion=83&part_number=132-BL-E758) you should update.

Comment: @Dmis - Its possible the memory problems are because of the processor I want to be able to look at the Intel website and verify something. Your motherboard does not suport a 16GB configuration. Its unlikely upgrading the BIOS will allow you to boot with 16GB installed but would likely resolve not being able the green DIMM slots. Since there are no specifications on your motherboard on EVGA's website I wasn't able to research it at all.  Your processor supports up to 24GB which means if you want more then 12Gb you need a different motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You likely experienced a comparability issue when trying to install sticks of RAM from more than one "kit". A single 6 × 4 GB or 3 × 8 GB kit would have booted just as your system did when you had installed 2 × 4 GB. Manufactures only guarantee memory compatibility of the modules in that specific package.

Yes, there are some hardware profiles that can get away with mix and match memory of different size, speed and manufacturer. Others, like yours, won't agree with a majority of ones with the same model number! Even lower quality RAM might only work with AMD CPUs on top of those requirements.